# Same set of Tasks are repeated in multiple stages in a Spark Job

Tags: apache-spark

A group of tasks consists of filters & maps appears in DAG visualization of multiple stages. Does this mean the same transformations are recomputed in all the stages? If so how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every [action](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions) performed on a dataframe, all transformations will be recomputed. This is due to the transformations not being computed until an action is performed.

If you only have a single action then there is nothing you can do, however, in the case of multiple actions after each other, then `cache()` can be used after the last transformation. By using this method Spark will save the dataframe to RAM after the first computation, making subsequent actions much faster.

Comment: lets say there are 5 narrow transformations followed by `reduceByKey()` then another 5 narrow transformations, in this case there will by 2 `stages`. My problem is first set of transformations appears in `stage2` also. will `cache()` just before `reduceByKey()` prevent it?

Comment: @vdep Yes, it should avoid additional transformations in this case.

Comment: @vdep can you include the actual code of what you describe as `transformations -> reduceByKey -> transformations` in the question? I'm curious about the exact example because `cache` will only be beneficial if you perform multiple actions on the same dataframe and it is not clear to me if that is the case here.

Comment: @vdep There is no need to cache if there is only a single action. Stages do not represent multiple actions but shuffle of the data. Thus, if there are multiple filters in different stages, then it's because you defined that in your application.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt, what you thought is partially true, though the transformation are to the same `RDD`, at the end i was joining to a different `RDD` causing the recomputation. I solved it by checkpointing.